Using Puppeteer/NodeJS to log into website
I'm trying to log into a website with my credentials and I always get the error from the website that says:

Here is the script (LoginOnly.js).  I tried to log as much as possible to the console, but still unable to figure out what I am not doing correctly.
// Import necessary modules
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
require('dotenv').config();

(async () => {
    // Launch the browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // Keep headless false for debugging

    // Open a new page (without using incognito)
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set custom User-Agent and viewport
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36');
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });

    // Stealth: Disable navigator.webdriver
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
            get: () => false,
        });
    });

    // Navigate to the main page
    await page.goto('https://hibid.com');

    // Click the login link to open the modal
    try {
        // Wait for the login link to be visible and click it
        await page.waitForSelector('.login-link', { timeout: 5000 });
        await page.click('.login-link');
        console.log('Clicked login link.');

        // Wait for the modal dialog to appear
        await page.waitForSelector('form', { timeout: 5000 });
        console.log('Login modal appeared.');

        // Get all input elements inside the form
        const formInputs = await page.$$('form input');
        console.log(`Found ${formInputs.length} input fields.`);

        // Loop through the input elements and fill them based on their types
        for (const input of formInputs) {
            const inputType = await (await input.getProperty('type')).jsonValue();
            console.log(`Filling input field of type: ${inputType}`);

            // Fill based on input type
            if (inputType === 'text') {
                // Assume this is the email/username field
                await input.click();
                await input.type(process.env.HIBID_USERNAME);
                console.log('Filled in the username.');
            } else if (inputType === 'password') {
                // Assume this is the password field
                await input.click();
                await input.type(process.env.HIBID_PASSWORD);
                console.log('Filled in the password.');
            }
        }

        // Click login button
        await page.click('button.btn-login');

        // Wait for login to complete
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        console.log('Successfully logged in.');

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error during login:', error);
        await browser.close();
        return;
    }

    // Close the browser after login
    await browser.close();

})();


I am at a complete loss after a lot of different attempts and different coding approaches.  I know I must be doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure it out :(

Likely the website is employing a backend captcha/verification service that checks stuff like user agent, ip reputation, mouse movement, headers, etc., and these are raising red flags suggesting you're a bot. If this is the case, you should research scraping and other bot techniques to make your browser look less suspicious. Opening the network tab in chrome devtools and finding the login request's response may also provide some insight.

I can see stuff when I log in normally.  Not really sure what I'm looking for, but I do see recaptcha_en.js being used

To make Puppeteer-controlled browsers appear less like bots, you can use the puppeteer-extra package along with the puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth plugin. Here’s how you can do it:
First, install the necessary packages:
npm install puppeteer puppeteer-extra puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

Then, use the following code to launch the browser with stealth mode enabled:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    // Other actions...
    await browser.close();
})();

This will help reduce the chances of your Puppeteer browser being detected as a bot but ofcourse wouldn't guarantee that.

I had tried this exact approach as well, same issue unfortunately.
